# Implementing two sample t-test in C

Tags: c

I am making a function that will calculate the test statistic from a two sample t-test and return it's value. However, I have been getting incorrect results. I previously was using `scanf` and got good answers, but it randomly stopped working. So I decided to switch to `fgets` which is suppose to be more reliable, however, the values it's returning are incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define VAL 10

double tstat(int x1,int x2,int s1,int s2,int n1,int n2);

int main()
{
    char mean1[VAL] = {0};
    char sd1[VAL] = {0};
    char n1[VAL] = {0};

    char mean2[VAL] = {0};
    char sd2[VAL] = {0};
    char n2[VAL] = {0};

    printf("Enter mean 1: \n");
    fgets(mean1, 10, stdin);
    printf("Enter sd 1: \n");
    fgets(sd1, 10, stdin);
    printf("Enter sample size 1: \n");
    fgets(n1, 10, stdin);

    printf("Enter mean 2: \n");
    fgets(mean2, 10, stdin);
    printf("Enter sd 2: \n");
    fgets(sd2, 10, stdin);
    printf("Enter n2: \n");
    fgets(n2, 10, stdin);

    printf("t value is: %lf", tstat(atoi(mean1),atoi(mean2),atoi(sd1),atoi(sd2),atoi(n1),atoi(n2)));
}

double tstat(int x1,int x2,int s1,int s2,int n1,int n2)
{
    double t = 0;

    t = (x1 - x2)/(sqrt(pow(s1,2)/n1+pow(s2,2)/n2));

    return t;
}
```

For example, setting `mean1 = 1.3`, `sd1 = 0.5`, `n1 = 22`; `mean2 = 1.6`,`sd2 = 0.3`, `n2 = 24` should yield a value of -2.44, however, plugging this in returns -1 followed by `#IND00`. I presume my issue is that either I am misinterpreting how to properly use `fgets`, or something is going wonky with the datatypes, though I am a beginner in C, and I have not been able to spot any clear errors.

Comment: `atoi()` ==> [`atof()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html), but try with [`strtod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) which is more reliable. Also make all parameters of `tstat()` be of type `double`.

Comment: You should always try to narrow down your problem. Every time you use data read from the user you first should theck whether reading the data works as expected. If you already fail in this step, you can ignore all the following steps in your code snippet. In this case this means that all the t-test stuff is not relevant at all if you read wrong data in first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are all of type `int` and you're using `atoi` to convert the strings to `int`.  However, the values you're entering aren't integers, they're floating point values, so only the integer part of each number is interpreted.  For example, `atoi("1.3")` results in 1.

You need to change your datatypes to `double` and use `atof` instead.

```
double tstat(double x1, double x2, double s1, double s2, double n1, double n2)
{
    double t = 0;

    t = (x1 - x2)/(sqrt(pow(s1,2)/n1+pow(s2,2)/n2));

    return t;
}

...

printf("t value is: %lf", tstat(atof(mean1),atof(mean2),atof(sd1),atof(sd2),atof(n1),atof(n2)));
```